# Warning: [react-router] Location "" did not match any routes for the rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-router

I am refactoring my rails code to React.

I am using the Link component:

`<Link to=url activeClassName="active">Admin</Link>`

When user clicks on the Admin Link then I get this error

> Warning: [react-router] Location "" did not match any routes.

The url changes to `/admin` but the page is not directed to the Admin Page. I guess because the Route is not present in the Router file.

But when I use anchor tags, it works as expected

`<a href=url> Admin </a>`

Can you help me figure a way out to use rails routes from react?